# How do I 'force' structs to implement the same traits?

Tags: rust, traits

I have the following:

```
pub struct OpBStruct {
    title: String,
    output_vale: i32,
}

impl OpBStruct {
    pub fn new_OpB(in_title: String, in_output_vale: i32) -> OpBStruct {
        OpBStruct {
            title: in_title,
            output_vale: in_output_vale,
        }
    }
}

pub struct OpCStruct {
    title: String,
    another_value: String,
    output_vale: i32,
}

impl OpCStruct {
    pub fn new_OpC(in_title: String, in_another_value: String, in_output_vale: i32) -> OpCStruct {
        OpCStruct {
            title: in_title,
            another_value: in_another_value,
            output_vale: in_output_vale,
        }
    }
}

impl A {
    pub fn new_A(in_name: String, in_operator: Op) -> A {
        A {
            name: in_name,
            operator: in_operator,
        }
    }
}

pub enum Op {
    OpB(OpBStruct),
    OpC(OpCStruct),
}

pub struct A {
    name: String,
    operator: Op,
}

impl A {
    pub fn new_A(in_name: String, in_operator: Op) -> A {
        A {
            name: in_name,
            operator: in_operator,
        }
    }
}
```

The exact structure of `OpBStruct` and `OpCStruct` are arbitrary and could be anything.

How do I make sure `OpBStruct` and `OpCStruct` implement a certain trait?

```
trait OpTrait {    
    pub fn get_op_output(&self) -> i32;
}
```

I thought about making a sort of constructor function that checked for an `OpTrait` trait requirement and it would be the only way one could create an `Op` instance, but each operator requires different initialization parameters and there's no way to specify a variable number of inputs for a function in Rust.

Something like this doesn't work because there's no way to input the initialization parameters:

```
pub fn new_op<T: OpTrait>(operator: T) {
    //  --snip--
}
```

I thought about somehow using the `new_A` method implemented on `A` to check if the `in_operator` has implemented the trait, but I'm not sure how to do that either.

What is the correct pattern for this? If there is none, I can just implement the trait for each `Op` with no sort of interface around it.

Comment: It'd help if you included the definitions of `OpBStruct` and `OpCStruct`.

Comment: There seem to be missing pieces in the code, which make the question hard to understand. Please seek to make a [MCVE]. Where are the definitions for `OpBStruct` and `OpCStruct`? What is preventing you from implementing the trait `OpTrait` for these two, and then for `Op`?

Comment: @E_net4, I have added an example of the how the structs could look.

Comment: Are you sure that the trait is declared the way you want? Implementing it for the given struct types should be trivial. Perhaps you would like to extend it to also include a generic constructor?

Comment: @E_net4, yeah sure it would be, but I wanted something like an interface from Java, where you have to implement the methods specified in the interface. So any new Op would have implement the OpTrait trait

Comment: You can already do that with traits. In fact, Java interfaces are even less flexible than Rust's traits. Can you show a concrete use case in code? I have a hunch of what you might be looking for, but I cannot provide an answer until the question is clear enough.

Comment: It sounds to me like, in Java terms, you're asking for `class Foo { String m; }` how to guarantee that `String` implements `IEnumerable`. Well... you don't. It either does, or it doesn't, but at the point you write `String` you're stuck with that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would also recommend writing a test, however you can write a function which is generic over a type but takes no arguments:

```
struct X {}

trait Y {
    fn yo();
}

fn is_y<T: Y>(){}
```

Then you can add the following line to do the check

```
is_y::<X>();
```

which will compile only if `X` implements `Y`.

Answer (score 0):

Using a unit test would be a fairly straightforward way to enforce that you want a given trait on a struct. You can do it via implicit test code, but a small utility function to do so can express the intent a little more clearly.

If you have indicated trait inputs on functions in the rest of the code, it might come out fairly naturally without the unit test. The test has the advantage of letting you have an opportunity to explicitly check some invariant of the trait implementation too.

```
struct A {
    val: u8,
}


struct B {
    val: u32,
}

trait ExpandToU64 {
    fn to_u64(&self) -> u64;
}

impl ExpandToU64 for A {
    fn to_u64(&self) -> u64
    {
        self.val as u64
    }
}

fn trait_tester<E>(a: E)
    where E: ExpandToU64
{
    // the utility function doesn't have to even use the trait...
    // but you probably want to exercise the logic a bit
    //let v = a.to_u64();
    let v = 24u64;
    println!("{:?}", v);
}

#[test]
fn test_needs_trait_ExpandToU64() {
    let a = A { val:1 };
    trait_tester(a);

    let b = B { val:2 };
    trait_tester(b);
    // This fails with a compile error
    //  "the trait `ExpandToU64` is not implemented for `B`"
}
```